# $\phi^4$ theory on lattice

Tags: lattice-model

After reading [this lecture notes](http://nic.desy.de/sites2009/site_nic/content/e44192/e62778/e91179/e91180/hmc_tutorial_eng.pdf) I am a little bit confused how points on the lattice gets assigned by a unique index j given in the lecture as

$$j = \sum_{i = 0}^{D-1} n_{i} L^{i}$$

Can any one explain what does it means. It is even not equal to total lattice sites V.

Comment: This is just a way to index the $L^D$ lattice points.  It's equivalent to giving each lattice point $j=(n_0,n_1,...,n_{D-1})$ an index whose digits in base $L$ are $n_0,n_1,...,n_{D-1}$ (from least to most significant).

Answer (score 1):

I'm suppose you are confused because the lattice is not 1 dimensional. As long as the model is discrete (i.e. the set of points on the lattice is a **[countable set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set)** you can always assign each point with index j and order the indexes in some order (the specific way of ordering does not matter. If you want to see an example of specific ordering please see [Cantor Pairing Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) ). Mathematically, this equivalent to the argument ${\displaystyle (\aleph _{0})^d=\aleph _{0}}$: